# How do I set the form of the point numbers in the list generated by numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I know `set_printoptions` determines the way floating point numbers are displayed.

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
np.random.uniform(size=(2,3))
```

Though, it does work for `tolist`

```
np.random.uniform(size=(2,3)).tolist()
[[0.6682122794117612, 0.8197401779902335, 0.003813536071464174],
 [0.8388311922778472, 0.2846408666954766, 0.33208962554534016]]
```

How do I set the form of the point numbers in the list generated by numpy, like this?

```
   [[0.5 , 0.8 , 0.17],
   [0.85, 0.81, 0.86]]
```

Comment: You could use [numpy.ndarray.round](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.round.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `around()` function of numpy to set the precision.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.uniform(size=(2,3))
x = np.around(x, decimals = 2)
```

Output

```
array([[0.77, 0.91, 0.97],
       [0.21, 0.65, 0.27]])
```